# pandas keeps category after removing corresponding variables from the dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

community,

given a simple example with an iris dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
df_iris = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                 columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])
df_iris['species'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)
df_iris = df_iris.drop("target", axis=1)
df_iris = df_iris[df_iris['species'] != 'setosa']
```

Why after filtering out setosa I still can see that category by printing df_iris.species?
[image]

This creates problems while trying to visualize data by seaborn afterward. Resetting the index for dataframe was not helpful. How I can remove setosa completely from dataframe?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's a function `remove_unused_categories` just for this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories.html

Comment: Thank you, that worked. However, I am a bit worried as this function is deprecated and probably will not be maintained in the future

Comment: @makkreker: Pandas is very aggressive about deprecating things, you never know what they'll deprecate next, even if people are using it and there's no obvious alternative.  You always have to be cautious when upgrading Pandas.